# It is found that $25\%$ of trucks fail to complete test run without blowout. Of next $15$ trucks tested find probability that $3$ to $6$ have blowout.

Tags: probability

In testing a certain kind of truck tire over rugged terrain, it is found that $25\%$ of the trucks fail to complete the test run without a blowout. Of the next $15$ trucks tested, find the probability that
**a.** from $3$ to $6$ have blowouts;
**b.** fewer than $4$ have blowouts;
**c.** more than $5$ have blowouts.

**Solution**

> [image]

I don't understand here that probability of failing without blowout is $25\%$ but in the solution probability of having blowout is also $25\%$.

Comment: I think you are reading the question wrong. It's not "(25% of the trucks fail to complete the test run) without a blowout", it's "25% of the trucks fail to (complete the test run without a blowout)". In other words, 25% of trucks *do* have a blowout.

Comment: I agree that this is hard to parse, but if you don't take $.25$ as the blowout probability, there is no other option.  (For what it's worth I would have otherwise parsed it as saying that $25\%$ of the trucks neither complete the course nor do they have a blowout but, as I say, this reading gives us no way to proceed on the computation).